# Capitalize everything after _ using REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex, uppercase

I want to capitalise everything following a _ using regex.

Example: from en_gb to en_GB

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a code writing service - how far have your own efforts got you?

Comment: I think that sounds like a good project for a beginner to tackle on their own while learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you should have tried some effort, but I am being nice on a Monday morning with a cup of coffee in my hand.

Use a replace function and use the argument to transform the string.

```
"en_gb".replace(/_.*/,function(a){return a.toUpperCase();})
```

Comment: thanks....and yes...I'm sorry I did not research a bit more!

Comment: THanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

This will should change change all after the underscore to uppercase. Tested works

```
var str="en_gb";
var splitStrg=str.split("_");
splitStrg[1] = splitStrg[1].toUpperCase();
var str = splitStrg.join("_");
```